# is there any way to find the spawn coordinates in a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a minecraft realm run by my friend, I've moved a couple of thousand blocks, but i want to go back to the world spawn, is there any way to do find the coordinates?\?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you can find out the spawn location.

## `/kill` yourself

I mean literally, type `/kill` in the chat to kill your character, and then check your coordinate when you respawn. If you, as the other posts are warning:

> keep on respawning next to a bed

Destroy the bed and `/kill` yourself again to return to the world's spawn point, or:

> keep on respawning somewhere else that is definitely not spawn

Sleep in a bed to reset your `/spawnpoint` and then destroy the bed and `/kill` again.

> random points

Use a compass (see below) or `/gamerule spawnRadius 0` first.

Default is `/gamerule spawnRadius 5`, `10`, or `16`.

## Use a [Compass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compass)

There's an [item in the game](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compass) that will always point to the world's global spawn point. You can use it to guide you back to the world's spawn point.

## Check your level.dat

Download your save file from Realms and check the `level.dat` of the game using an [NBT Editor](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer). [`SpawnX`, `SpawnY` and `SpawnZ`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_level_format) are the coordinates of the world spawn point.

Comment: The ```/kill``` method only works when gamerule spawnRadius is equal to 0. Otherwise, you will spawn randomly within that radius.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the specific coordinates, don’t want to die (keep inventory may be off), and you are quite far: get a friend who is closer to spawn to use a compass and they can press F3 and see the cordantes.

Answer (score 0):

/kill [your ign] will teleport you at the spawn, so you can use that.